# JQUERY AJAX .get can't access .php file on new server

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Recently I had a website move to a new server. Previously everything was working. Now, all of the `$().get("whatever.php")` fail. It doesn't even make it into the php script at all now.

For example:

index.html

```
$.get("test.php", function(data){
    alert(data);
}).fail(function(data){console.log(data)});
```

test.php

```
<?php
    echo "haii";
?>
```

The fail function logs:

```
Object { readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: .ajax/v.getResponseHeader(), getAllResponseHeaders: .ajax/v.getAllResponseHeaders(), setRequestHeader: .ajax/v.setRequestHeader(), overrideMimeType: .ajax/v.overrideMimeType(), statusCode: .ajax/v.statusCode(), abort: .ajax/v.abort(), state: .Deferred/d.state(), always: .Deferred/d.always(), then: .Deferred/d.then()}
```

Alternatively, the following still works perfectly (.get for **html**):

```
$.get("test.html", function(data){
    alert(data);
}).fail(function(data){console.log(data)});
```

The new server is a virtual private, very unsure if this could potentially impact this?

Lastly, all of these ajax calls are within the same domain folder.

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:

Attempting to open test.php on the server results in a 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: if you launch test.php in the browser, what happens?

Comment: hmmmmmm interesting,, I get a 500 internal server error....

Comment: lol, probably a permissions issue.

Comment: Even though everything associated with this is 775...? What other permissions do I need to configure ?

Comment: It was just a guess, it could be anything. Try turning on display_errors to see the actual error.

Comment: @Donal are you referring to the php display_errors? or another that i'm unaware of? .. As i can't use the php one because I physically can't load any php scripts XD

Comment: oh, yes, I see. It looks like you have bigger problems.

Comment: @Donal... A server side issue was the resulting cause, thank you for your comments though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

500 Internal Server means that file doesn't have permissions to execute, and this is the problem the ajax not working either.
just chmod the file to 644 and that it (it probably 666 right now)

Comment: The definition of the 500 internal server error you have posted is correct, however in my particular case, the issue was that the hosting company had disabled php for our particular account type XD... I literally couldn't run any php, even a simple echo "hello world" even when the file was on 777. Thanks for the answer though.